# How to find phrases where each word starts with a capital letter in Microsoft Word

Tags: regex, ms-word

What pattern can I use in MS Word's advanced find to highlight phrases where every word starts with a capital letter? The phrases have a varying number of words, and the words a varying number of letters.  If there is a full stop, or a word that starts with a lowercase letter, then that is the end of a phrase

Example of phrases to highlight

For the purposes of the **Legal Contract** he will email the **Signed AAA Document**.  **The Signed Reviewed Document** will then be archived.

Comment: Cant tell diferent betwebn Legal and Simon, what different ?

Comment: Just saw that error and was just about to modify :)

Comment: What have you tried? Please edit your post to include your code.

Comment: advanced find > check "Used wildcards" > the search term `<[A-Z]{1,}*>` . 
This highlights the words starting with a capital letter but I don't know how to get it to apply to a variable number of words with white space between them.  I think its something to do with [!.\ ] but I can't quite get it.

Comment: You *cannot* do this without VBA. As I said, please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i As Long
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "<[A-Z][A-Za-z]@ [A-Z][A-Za-z]@>"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    i = i + 1
    Do While .Words.Last.Next Like "[A-Z]"
      .MoveEnd wdWord, 1
    Loop
    .HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox i & " strings processed."
End Sub
```

For PC macro installation & usage instructions, see: http://www.gmayor.com/installing_macro.htm

For Mac macro installation & usage instructions, see: https://wordmvp.com/Mac/InstallMacro.html